# SABRE How to add excess baggage to your itinerary

Tags: soap, sabre

How do we add excess baggage to itinerary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service named AncillaryPriceRQ can be used to shop for air extras (additional products, including extra baggage) to be sold in addition to the flight tickets:

https://developer.sabre.com/docs/soap_apis/air/book/air_extras

Then, in order to add the item to the itinerary, the service UpdateReservationRQ can be used:

https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/management/itinerary/update_itinerary

Comment: whenever I try to search for BG the TTLPrice is  always 0 please help

Comment: Here's a sample:
http://webservices.sabre.com/drc/providerdoc/Merchandising/GetPriceListRQ_v.1.3.1_Design.xml

You can call the service having a PNR or not (check the RequestType element on the sample).

Total price for bags (and any other available ancillaries) will depend on how fares were filed for your agency.